# How to remove specific words that are repeated and add a word (if possible) to string

Tags: javascript, arrays, count

How to remove specific words on a string (and add the word "and" if possible) that are repeated twice but only twice and only certain characters?

Example: "Intruction in seated LE AROM x10 each instruction in standing LE AROM x10 each".

I want it to say, "Instruction in seated LE AROM and standing LE AROM x10 each".

I have tried looping through it and removing duplicates, but it removes duplicates that I do need. I also tried this that I found from somebody else's question, but they were just wanting to count how many times a word was repeated, so it didn't help me much.

```js
function removeDuplicate(str) {
   let words = JSON.stringify(str).toLowerCase().split(' ')
    
    let wordsCount = {}

    words.forEach(word => {
        wordsCount[word] = (wordsCount[word] || 0) + 1
    })
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily cout the occurrence of a word in a string then access a word via key or value.
Then select the words you want to keep or not in an `if(){}else{}` statement or a `switch` statement.

It's unclear to know the words what you want to keep and appears more than one time in the Array.

So here is a counter of occurrences then you'll have to delete some words in the Array arrToChange depending of your conditions and convert the Array to String again.

```js
            let originalString = "Instruction in seated LE AROM x10 each instruction in standing LE AROM x10 each";

            /* in arrToChange you may remove words by indexes found with arr (UPPERCASE), so the words will stay as written in the original string.*/

            const arrToChange = originalString.split(" ");
            const arr = originalString.toUpperCase().split(" ");
            const counts = {};

            for (const num of arr) {
                if(counts[num]){
                    counts[num] ++;
                }else{
                    counts[num] = 1;
                }
            }
            
            console.log("arrToChange = " + arrToChange);
            console.log("arr = " + arr);
            console.log("Object counts = ");
            console.log(counts);
            
            console.log("Object.keys   = " + Object.keys(counts));
            console.log("Object.values = " + Object.values(counts));
            
            // If you prefer to deal with an Array of Arrays
            // So here you get an Array like this:
            // [["Intruction",1],["in",2],["seated",1],...]
            console.log("");
            console.log("console.log(Object.entries(counts)); =>");
            console.log(Object.entries(counts));
```

Now you can count the number of occurrences and delete the words you want in Array arrToChange you just need yo get indexes of words to delete them...

Comment: As @FloT tell you : The example you give is not consistent with your explanations.

Answer (score 0):

The example you give is not consistent with your explanations.

Why is "Instruction" removed only once, whereas 'x10' and 'each' are removed twice? What 'and' is supposed to replace exactly?

If you just want to replace "x10 each" with "and", there's a build in JavaScript method doing this:

```js
const initial = 'Instruction in seated LE AROM x10 each instruction in standing LE AROM x10 each';
const wished = initial.replaceAll('x10 each', 'and');
// Instruction in seated LE AROM and instruction in standing LE AROM and
```

If you want to replace some words appearing twice with end, you can achieve this using `filter` and `includes` methods:

```js
const initial = 'Instruction in seated LE AROM x10 each instruction in standing LE AROM x10 each';
const toRemove = ['x10', 'each'];

function removeDuplicate(str, arr, repl) {
    const words = str.toLowerCase().split(' ');
    let wished = str;

    words.forEach(word => {
        if (words.filter(elem => elem === word).length === 2 && arr.includes(word)) {
            wished = wished.replaceAll(word, repl);
        }
    });

    return wished;
}
// Instruction in seated LE AROM and and instruction in standing LE AROM and and
```

But it seems that you ask for something else.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit hard to figure out exactly what you are trying to do. This is the closest I can get, without more input:

```js
const orig = "Instruction in seated LE AROM x10 each instruction in standing LE AROM x10 each"
const re = /\b(.+)(\s.*?\s)(.+)\s.*?\1(.*?)\3/
const result = orig.replace(re, '$1$2and$4$3')
console.log(result)
// => Instruction in seated and standing LE AROM x10 each
```

The regexp will capture the following (I will use `()` for the captures, and `{}` for re-matches of those captures):

```
( in)( seated )(LE AROM x10 each) instruction{ in}( standing ){LE AROM x10 each}
```

The `.replace` will then rearrange the sentence, by rearranging the four captures and adding the word "and":

```
( in)( seated )and( standing )(LE AROM x10 each)
```

However, there is nothing to distinguish "LE AROM" (which, according to your question, *should* be left repeated) from "10x each" (which should *not* be left repeated). Also, the only reason "Instruction" is not included in the match is because it happens to be in different case than its repetition ("I" vs "i"). If it is the literal words "LE AROM" that need to be repeated, you could add them to the second group explicitly:

```js
const orig = "Instruction in seated LE AROM x10 each instruction in standing LE AROM x10 each"
const re = /\b(.+)(\s.*? LE AROM\s)(.+)\s.*?\1(.*?)\3/
const result = orig.replace(re, '$1$2and$4$3')
console.log(result)
// => Instruction in seated LE AROM and standing LE AROM x10 each
```

Or, if you distinguish it by being all-uppercase, you can disallow uppercase from the third group:

```js
const orig = "Instruction in seated LE AROM x10 each instruction in standing LE AROM x10 each"
const re = /\b(.+)(\s.*?\s)([^A-Z]+)\s.*?\1(.*?)\3/
const result = orig.replace(re, '$1$2and$4$3')
console.log(result)
// => Instruction in seated LE AROM and standing LE AROM x10 each
```